# Redirect from :80 port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, redirect

There was a problem. Did a redirect for the site from http to https. The redirect periodically works, but the problem is that sometimes, when going to http://example.com, it throws to https://example.com:80 (for some reason it adds a port) and as a result does not go to the site with an error: "This site cannot provide a secure connection."
How to redirect, when adding: 80 at the end to a regular domain?

Htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding=cp1251
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Nginx:

```
user bitrix;
worker_processes 8;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  10240;
}

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/force-download;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    # Description of supported access log formats
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                  '$status "$request" $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format common '$remote_addr - - [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                    '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $msec';

  log_format balancer '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_iso8601] "$host" '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "schema: $scheme" '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                    '"$request_length" : "$request_time" -> $upstream_response_time';

    log_format debug '$upstream_response_time,"$time_local","$remote_addr","$request",$status,$body_bytes_sent';


  # upload default maps
  include bx/maps/*.conf;

  # settings files
  include bx/settings/*.conf;

    # Disable request logging in nginx by default
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  common;
    access_log          off;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    client_max_body_size        1024m;
    client_body_buffer_size     4m;

    # Parameters for back-end request proxy
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout      300;
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_buffer_size       64k;
    proxy_buffers           8 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size  10m;

    # Assign default error handlers
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    error_page 404 = /404.html;

    # Content compression parameters
    gzip                on;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_http_version       1.0;
    gzip_types          application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css;

    # add_header
    include bx/conf/http-add_header.conf;

    # Set default website
    include bx/site_enabled/*.conf;

    # Set additional websites
    include bx/site_ext_enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Curl test:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1 -i
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 10:25:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 303
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://127.0.0.1:80/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://127.0.0.1:80/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but if the original request used `http://example.com:80/` then the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` would generate `https://example.com:80/`. This question should probably be tagged `apache` rather than `nginx`.

Comment: Are you seeing `https://example.com:80` in the browser yourself? Or are you seeing this in the logs?

Comment: @MrWhite, browser redirects me.

Comment: Curious that this only happens "sometimes"? You appear to be using Nginx as a front-end proxy. It's quite probable that Nginx is adding the port number (possibly _after_ the Apache redirect?). See https://serverfault.com/questions/227742/prevent-port-change-on-redirect-in-nginx @RichardSmith